# What is the release schedule for the next Mac Pro (desktop)?

Tags: mac-pro

I work on many projects at once and my MacBook Pro is not cutting it anymore. I will be purchasing a [Mac Pro](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/mac_pro?mco=MTg5MTY5NDQ) (desktop) soon, but want to make sure a new model is not on the verge of coming out. Does anyone know the release schedule for the next [Mac Pro](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/mac_pro?mco=MTg5MTY5NDQ)?

Thanks, Chirag

Comment: Voting to close. Any answer here would be pure supposition and would be obsolete once the Mac Pro is released.

Comment: Yeah, this is too subjective. Who knows? Apple has no schedule, kinda sadly I'd say :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would wait. See http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/#Mac_Pro for the timeline of recent updates.

Comment: Thanks Brian. This ticket was closed every though 5 people found the answer useful. The release schedules on macrumors.com are indeed fact so I consider this a "good fit"

Comment: @Chirag The Macrumors Buyers' Guide is not a schedule: it is statistically-based guessing.